# An item with the same key has already been added. vsix project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, vsix, project-template

I am using multi-Project Vsix Template.

While I am adding multiple projects using same vsix template.

Steps:

1. Added New Project using Vsix project template. It created 2 projects successfully .
2. Again adding new project using same template. when I enter project name and click OK. It gave me error **"An item with the same key has already been added."**

I don't how to trace this error, why this is occuring?

Please Help..

Best Regards.